# BigQuery - REST API - Authentifikation / Autorisation

Tags: rest, google-bigquery

I cannot solvethe part how I make the Authorisation with my generated  JSON File (for an IoT device) -

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "wima20restbigquerydatastudio",
  "private_key_id": "30698752bb97d7c9c1e148356e27f5250375917d",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADA
/MgvflXMUVXnvYjRIJAaSBT7eFKTCWf4eag1cTQFGy\nUkUuksrhr4jLwtujPl8vlAO4...hiL\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "plc-wima@wima20restbigquerydatastudio.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "115146383911720147338",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/plc-wima%40wima20restbigquerydatastudio.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Can you give me an example how the syntax shoud look ?

Comment: I'd recommend reviewing https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production for more background.  There's no enough here to be more specific than that.

Comment: I need to generate an Automatic Token. I have a service account activated and a key. I try to connect to my BigQuery Dataset.